# How can I implement a DataTemplate into a subclassed Grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, grid, subclass

I have a `List<string>` that I need to display within a grid.
I need to be able to display each string inside of, for this question, let's say a `TextBlock`.

I've tried using an `ItemsControl` but it's not working the way I need it to work, so I'm considering sub-classing a grid control into an ItemGrid which would take as it's `DataContext` an `IEnumerable` ( and ignore anything else ) and also take an `ItemTemplate` which would tell the control how to display the contents.

I know how I would make it work with the `DataContext` to display the contents but I do not know how to implement a Template into the control.

My idea for the control is thus so far :

```
public class ItemGrid : Grid {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty
        ColumnCountProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ColumnCount",
            typeof(int),
            typeof(ItemGrid),
            new PropertyMetadata( 1, OnColumnCountChanged ) ),
        ItemSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ItemSource",
            typeof( IEnumerable<object> ),
            typeof( ItemGrid ),
            new PropertyMetadata( null, OnItemSourceChanged ) );

    private static void OnColumnsChanged(
        DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e ) {
        ItemGrid IG = sender as ItemGrid;
        IG.ColumnDefinitions.Clear( );

        for ( int c = 0; c < ( int )e.NewValue; c++ )
            IG.ColumnDefinitions.Add( new ColumnDefinition( ) {
                Width = new GridLength( 1, GridUnitType.Star ) } );

        OnItemSourceChanged(
            sender,
            new DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs(
                ItemSourceProperty, IG.ItemSource, IG.ItemSource ) );
    }

    private static void OnItemSourceChanged(
        DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e ) {

        ItemGrid IG = sender as ItemGrid;
        int x = 0, rows;

        //This is the stub.
        //this is where the objects would be passed on to the DataTemplate.
        IEnumerable<UIElement> Children =
        ( e.NewValue as IEnumerable<object> ).Select( Child => new UIElement( ) );
        foreach( UIElement Child in Children ) {
            IG.Children.Add( Child );
            x = IG.Children.IndexOf( Child );
            SetColumn( Child, x % IG.ColumnCount );
            SetRow( Child, x / IG.ColumnCount );
        }

        rows = IG.Children.Cast<UIElement>( ).Max( Child => GetRow( Child ) ) + 1;

        for ( x = 0; x < rows; x++ )
            IG.RowDefinitions.Add(
                new RowDefinition( ) {
                    Height = new GridLength( 1, GridUnitType.Star ) } );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get or Set Items Source.
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<object> ItemSource {
        get { return this.GetValue( ItemSourceProperty ) as IEnumerable<object>; }
        set { this.SetValue( ItemSourceProperty, value ); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get or Set Number of Columns.
    /// </summary>
    public int ColumnCount {
        get { return ( int )this.GetValue( ColumnCountProperty ); }
        set { this.SetValue( ColumnCountProperty, value ); }
    }
}
```

Within the `OnItemSourceChanged` method is a stub for selecting the objects into an `IEnumerable<UIElement>` which will then be distributed to the grid.

This is where I need to learn how to implement the DataTemplate, and that's where I need help.

I want to keep this in XAML as much as possible so that I can basically do something like this :

```
<Controls:ItemGrid ColumnCount = "2" ItemSource = "{Binding Foo}">
    <Controls:ItemGrid.Template>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text = "{Binding Bar}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Controls:ItemGrid.Template>
</Controls:ItemGrid>
```

And in doing so the grid will populate itself with the code behind.
Again - I've tried using an ItemsControl but it doesn't work ( even with all the help from [articles](http://garfoot.com/blog/2013/09/using-grids-with-itemscontrol-in-xaml/) [I've](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2010/11/15/using-a-grid-as-the-panel-for-an-itemscontrol.html) [read](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/), I can't get it to work the way that I need it to ).

How can I implement a Template into this control?

### EDIT :

For clarity, this is for what I am looking :

[image]

and I was able to find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207050/how-do-i-implement-a-wpf-control-with-its-own-datatemplate-dependencyproperty).

Comment: So you want do display it as a List from top to bottom or row-column style? If the first, you can use ListBox which support DataTemplate.

Comment: @Sakura I want it to display items like you would expect if you were reading a book, from Left to Right, Top Down.

Comment: `if you were reading a book` ? that mean each string is insert at the end of before string with same line ? Or each string with new line/row?

Comment: @Sakura ... Left to right, Top down, with a number of elements in each row equal to the column count.

Comment: ok then. see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an ItemsControl but set the ItemsPanel to a 2-column UniformGrid and set the ItemTemplate to be a TextBlock with appropriate bindings. You'll also want to wrap the whole thing in a ScrollViewer for when the control isn't high enough, but you'll also want to set the ItemsControl's vertical alignment to top so that the elements don't all get stretch out when the parent ScrollViewer is too tall:

```
<ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ItemsControl Name="myGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="2" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="50" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Center" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

If you only want 2 rows to be visible then lose the ScrollViewer, set the ItemControl's vertical alignment to stretch and specify `Rows="2"` in the UniformGrid:

```
<ItemsControl Name="myGrid">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="2" Rows="2" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="50" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Center" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```